# Ubuntu on laptop: opening a window on an HDMI external monitor via command line

Tags: xorg, 14.10, multiple-monitors

Using Ubuntu 14.10 on a Dell latitude, I'm trying to set up an external display connected through a mini-displayport.  Ideally, I would like to be able to open a custom full screen application on the external display, while maintaining a terminal on the laptop to display information.  In the past I've used the DISPLAY command such as:

```
DISPLAY=:0.1 'my program'
```

Unfortunately, the laptop is setting the monitors up as one large Screen 0.  xrandr gives output such as:

```
eDP1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
...
HDMI2 connected 1280x1024+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

So the external display is set up as an offset.  What are my options for having a 1280x1024 window open on the external monitor via command line (assuming I can't alter the program itself at this point)?

I've been trying to get an xorg.conf to set up with two Screens (0 and 1, where 1 is offset by 1366), but I can't seem to get it to work (using DISPLAY always returns: cannot open display: :0.1).

For context, if I just run the program now, it opens the window on the laptop at (0,0), while truncating the bottom obviously as it only has 768 to work with and I need 1280x1024 (looks like it's in a 1280x768 mode).